Need Guidance on Predictions with rand_forest and h2o with R
I have a random forest model that I'm trying to understand better.
For the sake of the example, lets say we have a grove of blueberry bushes. What we're interested in is predicting the production of rotten blueberries on a specific bush, among harvest of all blueberries of the individual bushes.
Each bush has an identifying name: bush_name, such as 'bush001', and we want predictions based on each individual bush. For example, I want to know if bush025 produced a rotten berry on 2/2/22.
Inputs are in a df with the following dummy structure for the sake of this example:
train_data <- data.frame(date = c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-07", "2022-02-09", "2022-05-01", "2022-11-01", "2022-11-02"),
                   bush_name = c("bush001", "bush001", "bush001", "bush043", "bush043", "bush043"),
                   bugs = c(2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1),
                   has_rotten_berry = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
                   berry_count = c(12, 1, 7, 100, 14, 4),
                   weather = c(1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1))

I've got a random forest model that I have set up with the following high level set up:
library(agua)
library(parsnip)
library(h2o)

h2o.init(nthreads = -1)

model_fit <- rand_forest(mtry = 10,  trees = 100) %>%
  set_engine("h2o") %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  fit(has_rotten_berry ~  .,
      data = train_data) %>% 
  step_dummy(bush_name) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors())

I do get this message after training:
Warning message:
In .h2o.processResponseWarnings(res) :
  Dropping bad and constant columns: [bush_name].

What I want to know is:
When I try to then predict on new data in the trained model, it seems that I am only able to input new test data with the bush_names of bushes I already trained on. Am I correct in assuming this model is creating bush-specific predictions? And therefore would have to input new bush information in the training in order to output a future prediction for those new bushes?
Example: I plant a new bush, bush700, and it was not present in the original training data set. If I try to predict with the new bush data without it being present in the training data, is giving me a message that there are new levels in the data. So I'm assuming that because it seems these predictions are bush-specific, and we can't get any new bush predictions for newly-added bushes.
Is this correct to assume?

The warning says your column 'bush_name' was detected as bad or constant and is not used during training. So, the result predictions are not based on this column.
If the column is not bad or constant (the bush_name data looks good in your example), it is used to train a model, and the result predictions are based on its values (levels).
If you put some unknown level in your test data, the model will create the prediction, but the prediction could not be as good as if the value were in the training dataset. That is the reason why we are raising the warning. However, the model will create some predictions for data with unknown levels.

The problem might be with bush_name being a character vector and not a factor vector. Since R 4.0, stringsAsFactors is set to FALSE so the character vector is not automatically converted to factors and H2O does not consider string vector as a valid input for most of its supervised algorithms.
You can use str() to inspect the structure of a data structure in R, this can be very useful for data.frames to find out what data types individual columns have. For example, when adding stringsAsFactors=TRUE the types of date and bush_name change types from character to factor:
> train_data <- data.frame(date = c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-07", "2022-02-09", "2022-05-01", "2022-11-01", "2022-11-02"),
                   bush_name = c("bush001", "bush001", "bush001", "bush043", "bush043", "bush043"),
                   bugs = c(2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1),
                   has_rotten_berry = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
                   berry_count = c(12, 1, 7, 100, 14, 4),
                   weather = c(1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1))
> str(train_data)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ date            : chr  "2022-01-01" "2022-01-07" "2022-02-09" "2022-05-01" ...
 $ bush_name       : chr  "bush001" "bush001" "bush001" "bush043" ...
 $ bugs            : num  2 0 1 0 3 1
 $ has_rotten_berry: num  1 0 0 1 1 0
 $ berry_count     : num  12 1 7 100 14 4
 $ weather         : num  1 0 2 0 1 1
>
> # Now let's add stringsAsFactors=TRUE to the data.frame function
> train_data <- data.frame(date = c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-07", "2022-02-09", "2022-05-01", "2022-11-01", "2022-11-02"),
                   bush_name = c("bush001", "bush001", "bush001", "bush043", "bush043", "bush043"),
                   bugs = c(2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1),
                   has_rotten_berry = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
                   berry_count = c(12, 1, 7, 100, 14, 4),
                   weather = c(1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1), stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
> str(train_data)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ date            : Factor w/ 6 levels "2022-01-01","2022-01-07",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ bush_name       : Factor w/ 2 levels "bush001","bush043": 1 1 1 2 2 2
 $ bugs            : num  2 0 1 0 3 1
 $ has_rotten_berry: num  1 0 0 1 1 0
 $ berry_count     : num  12 1 7 100 14 4
 $ weather         : num  1 0 2 0 1 1

However, I'd recommend to use the default and change the type afterwards (so the date is not converted to a factor vector) by using:
> train_data$bush_name <- factor(train_data$bush_name, levels=c("bush001", "bush043"))

Note the explicit enumeration of levels - you should use the same argument for test_data so that you ensure the same encoding of the factors.
You'll probably also want to encode the date column. H2O doesn't do any clever date preprocessing - at best it will represent date as a number of seconds since 1st January 1970 which is not ideal for rotten berry prediction as seasonality will likely have a bigger effect than number of seconds since some date. You can use step_date for date preprocessing.

Thank you! So if I dont want the predictions of bush_name to be specific (as in I want to be able to predict future bushes that havent been planted yet, vs retraining the model each time), then should I still convert bush_name into a factor?

For random forest you should probably remove the bush_name from training. But for, e.g., mixed-effects models (e.g., HGLM) you can use it to separate the influence of the individual bush and the other variables (you can see why it can be useful when you look at Simpson's paradox).
I would probably try to train it with and without bush_name and if the influence of having bush_name is big (in CV metrics), I would try to add some more information if possible, e.g., environmental factors - is the bush in the shade, is it more exposed to wind etc.

If I do 'step_dummy(bush_name)' is this similar to the factorizing of the variable? Thank you

Hi:  It looks like you are just trying to predict the rotten blueberries on a bush based on the predictors bugs, has_rotten_berry, berry_count and weather.  I will simply build a model with bugs, has_rotten_berry, berry_count and weather and ignore all the other columns.
The name of the berry bush should not matter to rotten blueberries.  The date is not important because this should be reflected by the weather column.
